# MySQL force query to return NULL

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have the following:

```
SELECT q25, COUNT( q25 ) AS count, AVG (q1) AS q1
FROM tresults WHERE id = 'Yes' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1' 
GROUP BY q25
```

At the moment, the query returns `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).` which is correct - is it possible to get it to return `NULL` instead?

**OR**

Is there a way of dealing with this after the event in PHP, such as:

```
$resultprev = mysql_query($queryprev);
if($resultprev == ''){
// do something
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a phpMyAdmin message. Where do you need the null exactly?

Comment: I need this otherwise other code doesn't run correctly.  I need the null under 'q1'.  Alternatively, can this be dealt with after, see the edit above.  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) :

```
$resultprev = mysql_query($queryprev);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultprev);
if($num_rows == 0){
   // 0 results !
}
```

or you could union a null row :

```
SELECT q25, COUNT( q25 ) AS count, AVG (q1) AS q1
FROM tresults WHERE id = 'Yes' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1' 
GROUP BY q25

UNION

SELECT null, null as count, null as q1
```

Comment: Answers the literal question, but seems rather convoluted for what the OP *actually* needs.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($res)) {
    //your stuff
}
```

or in sql

```
SELECT (
    SELECT q25, COUNT( q25 ) AS count, AVG (q1) AS q1
    FROM tresults WHERE id = 'Yes' AND date = 'MARCH2010' AND q25 = '1' 
    GROUP BY q25

    UNION

    SELECT null, null, null

) AS x
LIMIT 1
```